# AndroidX Room DAO implementation unreported exception when doing an insert

Tags: java, androidx

i'm trying to insert inside a room db, an object that i made that can throw an exception in its constructor. Android Studio does not build the app because of the unhandled exception, so i marked the insert method in the DAO interface with a throw, and the call to the insert method is inside a try/catch statement. However there is still a big problem: the DAO code generated by android does not handle the exception in any way, so i'm not able to build the code yet.

The call to the insert method:

...

```
    try {
        db.patternDAO().insertPatterns(thisPattern);
    } catch (GOLModel.LifeRuleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

...

DAO code:

```
@Dao
public interface PatternDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public void insertPatterns(List<Pattern> patternsToInsert) throws GOLModel.LifeRuleException;

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public void insertPatterns(Pattern... patternsToInsert) throws GOLModel.LifeRuleException;


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Pattern")
    public List<Pattern> getAllPatterns();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Pattern WHERE id = :id")
    public List<Pattern> getPatternById(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Pattern WHERE preferred == 1")
    public List<Pattern> getPreferredPatterns();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Pattern WHERE name LIKE :name")
    public List<Pattern> getPatternByName(String name);


    @Delete
    public void delete(Pattern... patternToDelete);
}
```

The object's constructor and the exceptions:

```
@Entity
public class Pattern implements Parcelable {

.
.
.    

// Constructors
public Pattern(int startX, int startY, String rule, String RLECode, String name) throws LifeRuleException, WrongParameter
{
    try {
        checkRule(rule);
    } catch (LifeRuleException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    this.rule = rule;
    this.RLECode = RLECode;

    if(startX < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("x is negative");
    else if(startY < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("y is negative");
    else if(startX < 0 && startY < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("both x and y are negative");

    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.name = name;
    this.preferred = false;
}

public Pattern(int x, int y, String rule, String RLECode, String name, boolean preferred) throws LifeRuleException, WrongParameter
{
    try {
        checkRule(rule);
    } catch (LifeRuleException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    this.rule = rule;
    this.RLECode = RLECode;

    if(x < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("x is negative");
    else if(y < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("y is negative");
    else if(x < 0 && y < 0)
        throw new WrongParameter("both x and y are negative");

    this.startX = x;
    this.startY = y;
    this.preferred = preferred;
    this.name = name;
}

.
.
.

public class WrongParameter extends Exception {
    private String message;

    public WrongParameter(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

}

the other one is just an exception that inherits from java.lang.Exception with empty body(i do not have created it :3 ). 
I tryied not to paste too much code and explain at the best, hope somebody can help

Thanks for your attention